# Meaning of DeleteItem Permission In Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I've run a powershell script to list all user permissions on mailboxes prior to a migration.

Some of the mailboxes have access rights listed as 'DeleteItem'.

What are these access rights and how do I go about amending them?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What are these access rights and how do I go about amending them?

Comment: What do you mean `amend` them? You want to modify the permission? You want to modify the users that have that permission? I don't understand what `amend` means in this context.

Comment: ah right - I want to find out what 'DeleteItem' access right entails so I can gauge whether or not they should be applied to these users. Then remove them if they shouldn't. I can't find them in EMS and they're not present in the folder permissions in Outlook.